# apply load balance to existing CRM 4.0 installation

Tags: dynamics-crm-4

i want to apply load balance to Microsoft Dynamics CRM 4.0, can i configure it on an existing installation? or do i have to install it all over again?

Thank you for your responses

Comment: Please keep in mind that this question is out of the scope of this site (at the moment the most appropriate place would be serverfault.com). If you are interested in the Microsoft Dynamics topic, please follow this [proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/32455/microsoft-dynamics?referrer=jHf4j_VcIgLKPEy52a9q2g2) on StackExchange.com in order to create an appropriate place.

Answer (score 0):

Please see this article which describes how to [Install Microsoft Dynamics CRM 4.0 Server on multiple computers](http://rc.crm.dynamics.com/rc/regcont/en_us/op/articles/crm_server_nlb.aspx)

If you already have a Dynamics CRM Server, you have to install the additional one(s) which you have to attach to the already created databases.

You have to use a unique service account for the application.